# Why isn't there an implicit typeof?

Tags: c#

I think I understand why this small C# console application will not compile:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void WriteFullName(Type t)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.FullName);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteFullName(System.Text.Encoding);
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler raises a CS0119 error: `'Encoding' is a type which is not valid in the given context`. I know that I can produce a Type object from its name by using the `typeof()` operator:

```
        ...
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteFullName(typeof(System.Text.Encoding));
        }
        ...
```

And everything works as expected.

But to me, that use of `typeof()` has always seemed somewhat redundant. If the compiler knows that some token is a reference to a given type (as error CS0119 suggests) and it knows that the destination of some assignment (be it a function parameter, a variable or whatever) expects a reference to a given type, why can't the compiler take it as an implicit `typeof()` call?

Or maybe the compiler is perfectly capable of taking that step, but it has been chosen not to because of the problems that might generate. Would that result in any ambiguity/legibility issues that I cannot think of right now?

Comment: Per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0119) > `"A class name was used instead of an instance name to refer to an array element."`.  When you wrap using `typeof()` you are getting an instance of `System.Type`, there is no instance equated with just typing in a namespace/class.  If you were using generics you could use it without `typeof()`, (i.e just give it a namespace/class)

Comment: Strong Typisations and lack of Implicit Conversions are a good thing. For the opposite cases, look at the PHP and JavaScrip examples from this Comic: http://www.sandraandwoo.com/2015/12/24/0747-melodys-guide-to-programming-languages/ The basic rule is that Implicit conversion only happen if no loss of data is possible. And with typeoff you convert between a Instance and it's type - that is 100% information loss.

Comment: Thanks @Christopher, but I was not converting between an object instance and its compilation type via `typeof()`, I was converting between a type name and its corresponding Type instance, which not only incurs in 0% information loss but actually expands the information provided by the type's name. While I do appreciate your interesting remark, I do not think it is applicable here. Nevertheless, Eric's post was very enlightening.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

> If the compiler knows that some token is a reference to a given type (as error CS0119 suggests) and it knows that the destination of some assignment (be it a function parameter, a variable or whatever) expects a reference to a given type, why can't the compiler take it as an implicit typeof() call?

First off, your proposal is that the compiler reason both "inside to outside" and "outside to inside" *at the same time*.  That is, in order to make your proposed feature work the compiler must both deduce that the expression `System.Text.Encoding` refers to a type *and* that the context -- a call to `WriteFullName` -- requires a type. **How do we know that the context requires a type**?  The resolution of `WriteFullName` requires *overload resolution* because there could be a hundred of them, and maybe only one of them takes a `Type` as an argument in that position.

So now we must design overload resolution to recognize this specific case.  Overload resolution is hard enough already.  Now consider the implications on type inference as well.

C# is designed so that in the vast majority of cases you do not need to do bidirectional inference because bidirectional inference is *expensive and difficult*.  The place where we *do* use bidirectional inference is *lambdas*, and it took me the better part of a year to implement and test it.  Getting context-sensitive inference on lambdas was a key feature that was *necessary to make LINQ work* and so it was worth the extremely high burden of getting bidirectional inference right.

Moreover: why is `Type` special?  It's perfectly legal to say `object x = typeof(T);` so shouldn't `object x = int;` be legal in your proposal?  Suppose a type `C` has a user-defined implicit conversion from `Type` to `C`; shouldn't `C c = string;` be legal?

But let's leave that aside for a moment and consider the other merits of your proposal.  For example, what do you propose to do about this?

```
class C {
  public static string FullName = "Hello";
}
...
Type c = C;
Console.WriteLine(c.FullName); // "C"
Console.WriteLine(C.FullName); // "Hello"
```

Does it not strike you as *bizarre* that `c == C` but `c.FullName != C.FullName` ?  A basic principle of programming language design is that you can stuff an expression into a variable and the value of the variable *behaves like the expression*, but that is not at all true here.

Your proposal is basically that **every expression that refers to a type has a different behaviour depending on whether it is used or assigned**, and that is **super confusing**.

Now, you might say, well, let's make a special syntax to disambiguate situations where the type is *used* from situations where the type is *mentioned*, and **there is such a syntax**. It is `typeof(T)`!  If we want to treat `T.FullName` as `T` being `Type` we say `typeof(T).FullName` and if we want to treat `T` as being a qualifier in a lookup we say `T.FullName`, and now we have cleanly disambiguated these cases *without having to do any bidirectional inference*.

Basically, the fundamental problem is that *types are not first class in C#*.  There are things you can do with types that you can *only* do at compile time.  There's no:

```
Type t = b ? C : D;
List<t> l = new List<t>();
```

where `l` is either `List<C>` or `List<D>` depending on the value of `b`. Since types are *very special expressions*, and specifically are **expressions that have no value at runtime** they need to have some special syntax that calls out when they are being used as a value.

Finally, there is also an argument to be made about likely correctness. If a developer writes `Foo(Bar.Blah)` and `Bar.Blah` is a type, odds are pretty good they've made a mistake and thought that `Bar.Blah` was an expression that resolves to a value.  Odds are not good that they intended to pass a `Type` to `Foo`.

---

Follow up question:

> why is it possible with method groups when passed to a delegate argument? Is it because usage and mentioning of a method are easier to distinguish?

Method groups do not have members; you never say:

```
class C { public void M() {} }
...
var x = C.M.Whatever;
```

because `C.M` doesn't have any members at all. So that problem disappears.  We never say "well, `C.M` is convertible to `Action` and `Action` has a method `Invoke` so let's allow `C.M.Invoke()`.  That just doesn't happen.  Again, *method groups are not first class values*.  Only after they are converted to delegates do they become first class values.

Basically, method groups are treated as expressions that have a *value* but no *type*, and then the *convertibility* rules determine what method groups are convertible to what delegate types.

Now, if you were going to make the argument that a method group ought to be convertible implicitly to `MethodInfo` and used in any context where a `MethodInfo` was expected, then we'd have to consider the merits of that. There has been a proposal for decades to make an `infoof` operator (pronounced "in-foof" of course!) that would return a `MethodInfo` when given a method group and a `PropertyInfo` when given a property and so on, and that proposal has always failed as too much design work for too little benefit. `nameof` was the cheap-to-implement version that got done.

---

A question you did not ask but which seems germane:

> You said that `C.FullName` could be ambiguous because it would be unclear if `C` is a `Type` or *the type `C`*.  Are there other similar ambiguities in C#?

Yes!  Consider:

```
enum Color { Red }
class C {
  public Color Color { get; private set; }
  public void M(Color c) { }
  public void N(String s) { }
  public void O() {
    M(Color.Red);
    N(Color.ToString());
  }
}
```

In this scenario, cleverly called the "Color Color Problem", the C# compiler manages to figure out that `Color` in the call to `M` means the *type*, and that in the call to `N`, it means `this.Color`.  Do a search in the specification on "Color Color" and you'll find the rule, or see blog post *[Color Color](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/07/06/color-color/)*.

Comment: But why is it possible with method groups when passed to a delegate argument? Is it because usage and mentioning of a method are easier to distinguish? Visual Basic .NET uses the `AddressOf` operator for this purpose, C# doesn't. You just specify the method's name.

Comment: simpler - why not allow `int x = "42";` Its totally obvious (grin) what was intended, so just do it

Comment: @pm100: "Figure out what the developer intended and do that" is a design principle of Visual Basic. It is *not* a design principle of C#!  The design principle of C# is "if it is not obvious what the developer intended or it looks like there might be a mistake, bring that to the developer's attention".  Both principles are reasonable, but they are opposites.

Comment: @EricLippert I had to unupvote that comment when you called the VB approach there reasonable. It's also the principle of JavaScript and PHP, and... well, let's just leave it at, no, that's not reasonable at all. lol.

Comment: Poster be like, "Damn! Eric just responded." LOL

Comment: @jpmc26: Specificity and pedantry go hand in hand (and are really just different takes on the same concept). C# gives you increased specificity (at the cost of more pedantry), whereas VB.Net (and the other languages you mentioned) gives you less pedantry (at the cost of less specificity). Both languages try to maximize a positive trait, but they each come with their own negative consequence. Just because two things are different does not mean one is objectively above the other. Just because a Ferrari is faster than a van doesn't mean UPS uses Ferraris for delivering packages.

Comment: @Flater Lack of specificity in computer programming leads to ambiguity. Ambiguity is never reasonable in programming. Granted, VB doesn't have ambiguity as far as I'm aware, but it hasn't earned a good reputation, either, and it's attempt to be more "friendly" and forgiving has a lot to do with that. In programming, clarity is king. Calling it "pedantry" wrongly dismisses its enormous value.

Comment: @jpmc26: I disagree; we *constantly* face ambiguous situations and must resolve them in C#; deciding when to make those ambiguities warnings and when to make them errors and when to make them nothing is as much art as science.  For example, if I have `namespace N { class M {} class B { public class M {} } class D : B { List<M> L; }` is `L` of type `List<N.M>` or `List<N.B.M>`?  It's ambiguous. C# makes a choice -- the latter -- and no warning. Is that the right thing to do, or would you prefer a warning in this case?

Comment: @jpmc26: For example: `class C { public static void M(short s) {} public static void M(double d) {}} ... C.M(123);` it is ambiguous which M is meant; both are applicable.  C# must decide which the developer intended, and does so without warning or error. (Choosing `M(short)`) Is that the right thing to do, or would you prefer a warning or error in this case?

Comment: @EricLippert I'd prefer an error; a warning would be better than nothing if an error is infeasible. Clearly, the better design choice is to rename one of those classes and avoid the problem entirely. The latter is less ambiguous because I should be able to consult the documentation for how C# decides the types of literals and eliminate the ambiguity, but I'd encourage a developer to somehow make the type explicit so it's clear what their intention was. Something else to point out there is that a named constant is probably a good design choice and would make the type explicit as well.

Comment: @EricLippert Actually, on second thought, if those two `M` methods don't provide the same functionality, one of them should be renamed. If they're the same thing, just different types, then it doesn't really matter which one gets called in terms of reasoning about the logic. If the type is important later on, though, I would encourage clarification like I said.

Comment: @pm100: "simpler - why not allow int x = "42";" Because that is **exactly** how we got those totally unpredictable JavaScript results here: http://www.sandraandwoo.com/2015/12/24/0747-melodys-guide-to-programming-languages/ How about we do not repeat mistakes that have been done decades ago?

Comment: @EricLippert and others. My comments was 100% misundertood. I meant that your explanation was correct. I was meaning "eric's explanation is very complicated explanation of why guessing is bad, a much simpler example of why its bad would be to just say 'we might as well allow int x = "42"'. In no way I am suggesting that we allow 'int x = "42"'

Comment: @jpmc26 Neither is 'better' than the other. As a regular user of both VB.NET and C#, I love the ability of the VB compiler to infer what I'm trying to achieve; it aids speed and productivity. I equally love the specificity of C# as it allows me to communicate my thoughts explicitly and unambiguously to the compiler. If anything, VB allows you to be explicit if necessary so I'd say it has a leg up over C#. Learn and appreciate both paradigms and you'll see they're really two sides of the same coin.

Comment: @AlexEssilfie I prefer an approach like Python's if you want speed and productivity: ambiguity is avoided almost completely, but there's a ton of flexibility and careful tuning of constructs to make common use cases incredibly easy, and yet without limiting you from dealing with the more complex cases.

Comment: @EricLippert I completely agree with everything you say, but why, why, why `$"string"` is a call resulting in a `string` unless you _ask_ it to be a `FormattableString`?..

Comment: @Lanorkin: This is a Q&A site: post a question! But try to phrase it as a "what" question. "Why" questions are vague and hard to answer.

Comment: @EricLippert I'm not _actually_ asking, I'm just commenting your reasoning - which again looks really reasonable for me - (put under _Why_  question!) with another language design decision which for me looks like contradict to those reasons

Comment: @Lanorkin: Ah, I think I understand. Your point is: an interpolated string is an expression with a particular type that is convertible to an unrelated type. Similarly, a qualified name that refers to a type could be treated as *convertible to a type* if the context requires it. I can see how that would work, but it would still suffer from the problem that there are confusing ambiguities.